# How to connect pins with ratsnest connection after netlist transfer in Proteus ARES

Tags: pcb-design, proteus, eda

I have a schematic file in Proteus-ISIS. I transferred into the ARES, after defining board edge and placing components, I placed 1x5 connector (CON5_1X5_U_FCI). But I could not connect pins of the  1x5 connector with the other part of the design which was transferred from the ISIS by ratsnest connection.[image: ares circuit].

In this circuit I could not connect 4.pin of the 1x5 connector to the 13. pin of mcu. When I clicked to 13. pin of mcu the green line (ratsnest line) disappears. How can I handle this situation? By the way this circuit is set up for only demonstration. I tried this with Proteus 7 and 8.0.

The error message is: "Cannot add manual connection here!"

Comment: Are all your connections correctly made on the schematic? If so, is this a power or ground connection? These may be treated differently (assuming you mean to use a ground plane) and not appear as ratsnests.

Comment: 1.Yes, connections made in schematic is transfered to ARES correctly. 2.No, the pins that I was trying to connect are not power or ground pins.

Answer (score 2):

try using the ares auto-router it should connect them for you. if this fails then you can manually add a track between the two pins as folows.
select the manual route icon, choose the top layer, left click on pin13 to start manual routing mode, left click anywhere you want the route to go, then left click on pin 4, then right click on pin 4 to end manual routing. a track should be placed between the two pins following the route you traced.